# Tensor product of t-structures compatible with filtered colimits

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, t-structure

Let $C,D$ be two stable presentable $(\infty,1)$-categories, equipped with accessible t-structures. Then you can define an accessible t-structure on $C\otimes D$ by having $(C\otimes D)_{\geq 0}$ be generated under colimits by objects of the form $c\boxtimes d$, $c\in C_{\geq 0}, d\in D_{\geq 0}.$ (Here I use the homological degree convention.) This construction appears in e.g., Section 4.6 of Lurie's DAG VIII.

My question is: If $C$ and $D$ have t-structures compatible with filtered colimits (meaning that $C_{\leq 0}$ is closed under filtered colimits), is the t-structure on $C\otimes D$ compatible with filtered colimits?

The strongest result I know is that this is true if the t-structures on $C$ and $D$ are right-complete. This follows from Theorem C.4.2.1 in SAG (tensor products for Grothendieck pre-stable categories). The proof in this case is already quite nontrivial...

On the other hand I occasionally find this statement tacitly assumed in the literature, so perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Let's assume that $C,D$ are compactly-generated for simplicity (so $C \otimes D$ is also compactly-generated). With this assumption, note that if $C_{\geq 0}$ and $D_{\geq 0}$ are generated by compact objects (which implies that $C_{\leq 0}, D_{\leq 0}$ are compatible with filtered colimits, but maybe is not equivalent to this?) then $C_{\geq 0} \otimes D_{\geq 0}$ is also generated by compact objects, and so $(C\otimes D)_{\leq 0}$ is compatible with filtered colimits.